# Can Silverlight initiate Page Refreshes?

Tags: silverlight-2.0

UPDATE: An alternative title for this could be: How do I call javascript from my silverlight 2.0 application.

Here is a quick question for all you Silverlight gurus.

I have a Silverlight app that displays a stopwatch countdown. The app is hosted in an ASP.Net web application, 
What I want it to do is when the stopwatch hits zero, the app forces a server page refresh of the hosting page.

Is this possible?

If so, any chance of a code snippet?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[Apparently](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2008/03/09/calling-javascript-functions-from-silverlight-2.aspx) you can call a JS script from Silverlight using

```
HtmlPage.Window.CreateInstance
```

or

```
HtmlPage.Window.Invoke
```

The JavaScript to [refresh](http://www.quackit.com/javascript/javascript_refresh_page.cfm) a page is

```
location.reload(true)
```

I'm not a Silverlight or JavaScript expert though, so not sure if it works in all browsers, or even at all.

**EDIT:**

Scott posted a comment to this answer with his final solution.

He needed to create a JavaScript client function on the ASP.Net page called reload() that did the location.reload(true). Then it was a simple matter from his C# code to reload:

```
HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("reload");
```

As @R4cOON suggested, you can also use:

```
System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Document.Submit();
```

Comment: HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("location.reload(true);"); didn't work for me after all. When I find out exactly what does, I'll post it here. thanks anyway.

Comment: ok, this was 90% of the way there.
All I needed was to create a javascript client function on the ASP.Net page in my case, called reload(), that did the location.reload(true).
Then it was a simple matter from my C# code to have this line:
HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("reload");
Thanks again.

Answer (score 25):

Why not simply stay on the Silverlight side and call

```
System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Document.Submit();
```

Works a treat for me. The whole page gets reloaded and the Silverlight control kicks backs in.

Comment: This was exactly the sort of thing I was looking for. I'll check it out soon, and +1 your answer if it works the way I was expecting. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean? Of course it won't work on the server, Silverlight is on the client side!
Do you mean you want to restart your web server from the client?

Comment: This works if the page has a <form> element on it (e.g. any Web Forms page). Without a <form> element (e.g. many ASP.NET MVC pages), there is nothing to submit, and you get an InvalidOperationException.

Answer (score 6):

Just a quick note on why `HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("location.reload(true);");` doesn't work: it appears from my quick testing that the way Silverlight implements Invoke is to look up a property with the given name on the specified JavaScript object and call it.  So this code would say, "Find a property on the window object named 'location.reload(true);' and call it with zero arguments."  There is, instead, a `GetProperty` method that will let you get the window's `location` property and invoke `reload` on that with the parameter `true`.  The final code looks like this:

`((ScriptObject)HtmlPage.Window.GetProperty("location")).Invoke("reload", true);`

Comment: This is a good option if the host HTML page does not contain a form element that can be submitted.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I didn't want to do asp.net kind of postback and lose my Silverlight page context so I refreshed my page by navigating to it. That way my language changes I made in my nav bar were reflected on my page or View as they come in 2008 template.

this.ContentFrame.Navigate(new Uri("", UriKind.Relative));

In this case I was on my home page. "" means home page if you examine the Silverlight templated navigation solution.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible for a silverlight app to call out into javascript on the page which in turn could force your page refresh. So yes this is definitely possible!