# How to redirect a Silverlight application to ASP.NET login page on timeout?

Tags: asp.net, silverlight

I have a requirement in my Silverlight 5 app hosted in an ASP.NET site with FormAuthentication with 5 min timeout. I have a client requirement that when the session timeout occurs the next user request must be redirected to login.aspx and login again.

Currently I have this in `Application_UnhandledException` handler:

```
if (domainException != null && !WebContext.Current.User.IsAuthenticated) {
    e.Handled = true;
    System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Document.Submit(); // redirect to login page
}
```

Thanks 
Elio

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318703/redirect-to-another-page-from-silverlight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with - based on `Navigate Method`

```
System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(new Uri("url", UriKind.Absolute));
```

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/cc189809(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: Thanks Yakoub, that worked well for redirecting the user, but i'm struggling trying to catch timeout. Currently i have this in Application_UnhandledException in App.xaml.cs:
var domainException = e.ExceptionObject as
 System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.DomainOperationException;
if (domainException != null && !WebContext.Current.Authentication.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) {
    e.Handled = true;
    System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(new           Uri("login.aspx", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
}

Comment: I'am happy to help you user1676134 you can get your timeout from config file

Comment: I finally get it working the timeout part:
http://forums.silverlight.net/p/215349/510305.aspx