# Refresh browser (IE, FF, Opera) via C# code

Tags: c#, firefox, internet-explorer-8

I need to refresh browser via c# code and google keeps silence. Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Well, I have browser opened. And i need to refresh it via c# program. So my question is - can I tell something to browser process (somehow) to make it refresh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The awful, round about way to do it is to attach WatiN to the process (find the HWND, attach that way, most likely) and call Browser.Refresh().

Answer (score 0):

Consult your browser's documentation for exposed APIs that may allow you to refresh the browser page from a different application, then perform whatever appropriate interop is required to refresh the page.

Answer (score 0):

So, you can't do it with C#, because C# isn't used on the browser.  You can do it through JavaScript though.

```
<!-- Codes by Quackit.com -->
<a href="javascript:location.reload(true)">Refresh this page</a>
```

http://www.quackit.com/javascript/javascript_refresh_page.cfm

or:  [Meta refresh Tag](http://webdesign.about.com/od/metataglibraries/a/aa080300a.htm)

If you wanted to split hairs, you could technically, do it in silverlight, but that really just ends up calling JavaScript:

[Can Silverlight initiate Page Refreshes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/552756/can-silverlight-initiate-page-refreshes)

Answer (score 0):

```
Response.Redirect("the_page_you_want_to_refresh.aspx");
```